# The universal sub-bundle on Gr(2,4) is stable and exceptional

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannian

The universal sub-bundle and the dual of the universal quotient bundle on $\operatorname{Gr}(2,4)$ are specific examples of spinor bundles on a quadric. They arise from an irreducible representation of a semi-simple Lie algebra. In the paper of Ottaviani (1988), a theorem of Ramanan is quoted to argue that spinor bundles are stable.

I was wondering if there is a direct and elementary way to prove the stability of a spinor bundle on the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(2,4)$, and why is it exceptional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a 4-dimensional vector space and let $S$ be the universal subbundle on $\mathrm{Gr}(2,V)$. Let $0 \ne f \in V^*$ and consider it as a global section of $S^*$. Then its zero locus is the sub-Grassmannian
$$
\Pi := \mathrm{Gr}(2,V_f) \cong \mathbb{P}^2,
$$
where $V_f \subset V$ is the annihilator of $f$. Therefore, there is an exact sequence (Koszul complex)
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \to S \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_\Pi \to 0.\tag{*}
$$
Since $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ has no cohomology, while $H^\bullet(\mathcal{O}) = H^\bullet(\mathcal{O}_\Pi) = \Bbbk$
is the base field, it follows that
$$
H^\bullet(S) = 0.
$$
In particular, the vanishing of $H^0(S)$ implies the stability of $S$.

Tensoring $(*)$ by $S^*$, we obtain
$$
0 \to S \to S \otimes S^* \to S^* \to S^*\vert_\Pi \to 0.
$$
Now $S$ has no cohomology, while
$$
H^\bullet(S^*) = V^*,
\qquad
H^\bullet(S^*\vert_\Pi) = V_f^*,
$$
and the map is the restriction (the dual to the embedding $V_f \hookrightarrow V$), hence it is surjective and its kernel is 1-dimensional. This shows that
$$
H^\bullet(S \otimes S^*) = \Bbbk,
$$
hence $S$ is exceptional.

Comment: Following the vanishing of $H^0(S)$, can I argue as the following? The Picard group of $\operatorname{Gr}(2,4)$ is generated by $\mathcal{O}(1) \cong \det S^\vee$. Suppose that $L$ is a line bundle which destabilizes $S$, then $\deg L > \deg S/2 = -\deg \mathcal{O}(1)/2$. If $L = \mathcal{O}(a)$ then $a \geq 0$. So $L$ has global sections, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, precisely.